# webform ajax callback response not updating text, is something missing?

Tags: 8, webforms

The code below works inside hook_form_alter.  The description and price update from database as desired when in form_alter.  I moved the code to the callback and now it wont return/update the values. I use a button to call the ajax callback. The throbber shows and then no change.
Partial of custom module, using a button for testing the callback

```php
    if ($form_id=='webform_submission_srvform_add_form' && $form_state->isExecuted()) {
        $lkuppage='';
        $lkuppage=$form_state->get('current_page');
    switch ($lkuppage) {
        case 'billing':
            $form['elements']['billing']['items_update'] = [ 
                '#type' => 'button', '#value' => t('Update prices'),
                '#ajax' => [ 'callback' => 'srvform_items_callback', 'event' => 'click',
                'progress' => [ 'type' => 'throbber', 'message' => t('Updating line items...')] ] ];
            $form['elements']['billing']['desc01']['#prefix'] = '<div id="ajax-desc01">';
            $form['elements']['billing']['desc01']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```

and the callback

```php
function srvform_items_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $lkuppart='';
    $lkupok='yes';
    $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
    $lkuppart=$form['elements']['billing']['itemflex01']['part01']['#default_value'];
    if (!empty($lkuppart)) {
        $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node') ->condition('type', 'parts') ->condition('title', $lkuppart);
        $nids = $query->execute();
        $lkupnodes = $node_storage->loadMultiple($nids);
        foreach ($lkupnodes as $nodecnt) {
            $lkuptitle=$nodecnt->title->value;
        }
        if ($lkuptitle <> $lkuppart) {
            $lkupok='false';
        } else {
            $form['elements']['billing']['desc01']['#default_value']=$nodecnt->body->value;
        }
        $lkuptitle='';
    }
    $lkupdesc = $nodecnt->body->value;
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#edit-desc01--value', $lkupdesc));
//    $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand('[data-drupal-selector="edit-desc01"]', $lkupdesc));
//    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#ajax-desc01', $renderer->render($form['elements']['billing']['desc01'])));
$response->addCommand(new AlertCommand(t($lkupdesc)));
    return $response;
```

Is it simply a bad/obsolete command I am using?
The AlertCommand works, returns the part description in a window.
Unable to replace the desc01 value with any of the above. syntax? or ?

Comment: Where do you attach the callback to the field? In other words, how are you telling Drupal that your callback function is `srvform_items_callback()`?

Comment: Can you please update with the code you have used to assign the callback. Also do check your browser developer toolbar / network tab to see what is the response you get from the server for the request you are sending from the form via ajax if the throbber is showing and there is an actual ajax request being sent.

Comment: also try changing ReplaceCommand with HtmlCommand so can happen more then once as replace ... removes the wrapper element where as HtmlCommand does not

Comment: Rewrote the code and tried many variations, unable to update description value